# Is it possible to play with 7 players locally (and online)?

Tags: ps3, fifa-13

There seems to be some mixed information online about the number of players supported in PS3 FIFA 13. Some of the pre-release ads claimed this to be 2-10 online, and 4 locally.
I've played in some 11 vs. 10 matches online, so clearly the original info was wrong, but how many players can you have on one console? I only own 2 controllers, and would like to avoid buying/borrowing a lot more of them, if the game doesn't properly work with 4+ players.

So, does FIFA support all the 7 available controllers in friendlies or are there other restrictions? Has anyone actually tried playing with more than 4 players?

Is it possible to play online with 6 friends in the various games modes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The game's cover states local players to be 1-7 and network players to be 2-22 (zoom in on the image to look closely). 
[image: FIFA 13 cover]

Since the max controllers supported at the same time on a single PS3 is 7, online support is at least for 4 consoles (3 consoles * 7 players + 1 console with 1 player or similar configurations). I don't know the exact number of consoles supported.

Try checking [the game's manual](http://eacom.s3.amazonaws.com/FIFA13ps3MANOLeWW_FINAL.pdf) (Warning: PDF) for further info.

Comment: OK. So in theory it works, but does it in practice? Any experience with this?

Comment: I don't own the game, so no. I can ask friends on my PSN friend list who own the game if they have any experience

Comment: Wait, how does this support 7 local players?  I thought the PS3 only supported 4 controllers.

Comment: 7 controllers, as long as no other bluetooth devices (remote, headset) are connected. Not many games support this, though.

Comment: I've seen 4+ controllers in NHL something but never seen FIFA for this. I'm assuming most EA Sports games actually do support lots of local players. Annoying restriction with 7, not 8 controllers, though.

Comment: The restriction comes from a limitation of the bluetooth technology used by the remotes

Comment: Accepted the answer. 7 was indeed supported, but some controllers behaved somewhat weird. Might have been a problem with one or two controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we play with 6 controllers locally with 3 on each side and with no problems. 7 th one can also be used if required. Never tried this online.